# Xcode iOS deployment target check?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, deployment-target

On more than one occasion, I have accidentally changed the deployment target of my Xcode project to something I don't want.  The latest time, I found out because a customer wasn't seeing my app.  Is there a way to put something into my code somewhere to assert the value of the deployment target?  I think I would be much less likely to change that by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check your deployment target version via `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` macro and compare it to some sdk version, e.g. to make sure that your deployment target is 4.0 put the following lines somewhere:

```
#if  __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED != __IPHONE_4_0

#error wrong deployment target - should be 4.0

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a **New Run Script Build Phase** to your target and put this script inside:

```
DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_VALID=`expr ${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET} \>= "4.0"`;
if [ $DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_VALID = 1 ]; then
    echo "Deployment target ($IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) is too high."
    exit 1
fi;
```

Here, build will fail if the deployment target is set to 4.0 or higher.